# image background with z-index: -10, fails when using jquery animate opacity

Tags: css

I have a simple fadeIn/fadeOut page transitions where I append the pages with Jquery.

Each page have a fullscreen background, below is the CSS:

```
  img.bg {
    /* Set rules to fill background */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;

    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    /* Set up positioning */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -10;
  }
```

This is demo file http://daisyabdulazeez.com/test/

I tried to recreate the problem but I couldn't do it http://jsbin.com/cujuwego/1

please help.

**edit**

My goal is to have the bg image stays behind the header+footer, if you see the demo file, the bg image overlaps the header+footer during transitions but my jsbin doesn't

Comment: please tell us more about your desired output.

Comment: My desired output is to have the z-index stays. if you check my demo the bg image overlaps the header during transitions where as my jsbin doesn't

Comment: i am getting error like `Cannot connect to the real dl.dropboxusercontent.com` for your demo.

Comment: please check here http://daisyabdulazeez.com/test/

Comment: I think u need to stop animation on certain time.. its not stopping .. thats why u not able to see effect.

Answer (score 4):

```
#header, #footer {position:relative; z-index:999;}
```

Add position value and z-index for both header and footer